# i want to fetch data into javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am new at laravel and  I want to fetch data from a database into script code but unfortunately, I don't know how to do that please Does anyone have an idea please help me thanks.

please check the image here https://ibb.co/Km75pQS

**response here**

```
[
  {
    "id": 160,
    "year": 2020,
    "name": "Mazhab e Islam ki Mubarak 
       Taleemaat",
    "audio_file": null,
    "slug": null,
    "downloads": null,
    "date": "2020-06-08",
    "type": 5,
    "sort": null,
    "status": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-10-20T17:37:59.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-20T17:43:13.000000Z"
  }
]
```

**controller**

```
  public function fridaySermon()
        {
    
            $data = [
    
                'fridaySermons' => Audio::where('type', 5)->get(),
    
            ];
            return view('friday-sermon', $data);
        }
```

**script**

```
 // initialize playlist and controls
        var index = 0,
            playing = false,
            mediaPath = '{{url('')}}/assets/friday-sermon/',
            extension = '',
            tracks = [
                     // get data here 
                {
                "track": "<i class='fa fa-headphones'></i>",
                "name": " <span class='playerTitle'>Title:</span> Mazhab e Islam ki Mubarak Taleemaat <span class='bottomPlyrDcsp'><br> <span><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i> 20-Mar-2020 | <i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> 20:34 | <i class='fa fa-download'></i> 558</span></span>",
                "duration": " <i class='fa fa-play-circle'></i>",
                "file": "20-mar-2020"
            }],
            buildPlaylist = $.each(tracks, function(key, value) {
                var trackNumber = value.track,
                    trackName = value.name,
                    trackDuration = value.duration;
                if (trackNumber.toString().length === 1) {
                    trackNumber = '0' + trackNumber;
                }
                $('#plList').append('<li> \
                    <div class="plItem"> \
                        <span class="plNum">' + trackNumber + '</span> \
                        <span class="plTitle">' + trackName + '</span> \
                        <span class="plLength">' + trackDuration + '</span> \
                    </div> \
                </li>');
```

Comment: put this data in tempalte... show your template for this view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly broad question, but at it's base your need to, from your "front end" (js/jQuery), make a request to your "back end" Laravel application.

To do this I would recommend using the JS Fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (there are other ways if necessary) from your front end application.

Before you request your data from your Laravel API, the back end Laravel API will need to have endpoints configured to actually provide the data that is being asked for. Here is an example tutorial: https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial

There are many tutorials like this, so feel free to find whichever one works best for yourself.